A2C gradient calculation
Can someone explain how to calculate the graident of bias term at the output layer?
I compared the result from calculate directly with result from PyTorch and it returned difference value.
For now, I understand that I need to find the derivative of loss function first (In this case is Policy loss function and activation function is SoftMax), then multiply with advantage value.
Equation to calculate gradient of bias term at output layer
This following code is the code that I have used to compare result from PyTorch and result from Manually calculate.
PyTorch
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Example: simple neural network
model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(4, 3),  # Input: 4, Hidden: 3
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.Linear(3, 2),  # Hidden: 3, Output: 2
    nn.Softmax(dim=1)
)

# Dummy input and output
x = torch.randn(5, 4)  # 5 samples, 4 features
y = torch.tensor([0, 1, 1, 0, 1])  # 5 samples, class labels

# Loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)

# Forward pass
outputs = model(x)
loss = criterion(outputs, y)

# Backward pass
optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear previous gradients
loss.backward()  # Compute gradients

# Access the gradients of the parameters
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if param.grad is not None:
        print(f"Gradients for {name}:")
        print(param.grad)

Manually calculate
# Manually calculate forward pass
z1 = torch.matmul(x, model[0].weight.T) + model[0].bias
a1 = torch.relu(z1)  # ReLU activation

z2 = torch.matmul(a1, model[2].weight.T) + model[2].bias
a2 = torch.softmax(z2, dim=1)  # Softmax activation

# print("a2 ",a2)
# print("y ",y)
# Compute loss
loss = criterion(a2, y)

# Compute gradient of loss with respect to output of softmax (cross-entropy)
dL_da2 = a2.clone()  # Copy the output to prevent altering it
dL_da2[range(len(y)), y] -= 1  # Subtract 1 from the correct class' probability
# print("dl_da2 ",dL_da2)
dL_da2 /= len(y)  # Normalize gradient

# Backpropagate through softmax layer
dL_dz2 = dL_da2  # Gradient of loss w.r.t. z2 (output before softmax)
# print("dL_dz2 ",dL_dz2)

# Gradients for weights and biases of layer 2 (output layer)
dL_dw2 = torch.matmul(dL_dz2.T, a1)
dL_db2 = dL_dz2.sum(dim=0)
print(dL_dw2)
print(dL_db2)

# Backpropagate through ReLU and first linear layer
dL_da1 = torch.matmul(dL_dz2, model[2].weight)
dL_dz1 = dL_da1.clone()
dL_dz1[z1 <= 0] = 0  # ReLU derivative

# Gradients for weights and biases of layer 1 (hidden layer)
dL_dw1 = torch.matmul(dL_dz1.T, x)
dL_db1 = dL_dz1.sum(dim=0)

I want to know how to mannually calculate the back-propagation of actor network at the output layer.
